# Is there a way to record a div on click and then convert the recording to a gif?

Tags: javascript

I have a site that is interactive, and I'm wanting to record a specific div when someone clicks on a button. Is there a way to record a div upon click of that button, and then convert that recording into a gif? How hard would this be to do? Can you help me think of a solution that might work?

I'm trying to record the screen view of the div, it has some animations in it that I would like users to be able to turn into gifs. But depending on what they submit the animation is different.

Comment: I think you would have to generate a sequence of images with something like [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and then send those images to a js 2 gif library, something like [this](https://github.com/sole/Animated_GIF)

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have any code you can post?